# bijective mapping homework question

Tags: combinatorics

I have to answer a question which i don't really understand. The question is:

Find an appropriate bijective mapping between a set of sequences and the set in question:
1. In how many ways can $k$ elements be chosen from an $n-element$ set 
$\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}...x_{n}\}$

This is my answer of forming a bijective mapping but i'm not sure if this is even the right way to do it.


$A=\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}...x_{n}\}$
$B=\{n+1$ bit sequence with exactly 1 ones$\}$
$B=\{\underbrace{0...0}_\text{k}$ 1 $\underbrace{0...0}_\text{n-k}\}$

This is bijective since $|A|=|B|$

Did I answer the question correctly or did I completely misunderstand the question?

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me as if you are asked to find a bijective mapping between the collection of subsets of your set that have $k$ elements, and a set of sequences. The usual one would be the mapping that takes a subset to the sequence of $k$ $1$'s and $n-k$ $0$'s that tells you which elements are in the subset.

Comment: ok so the set B would be defined as: B={n-k 0s and k1s} ?

Comment: The set $B$ is the set of all $n$-bit sequences that have $k$ $1$'s and $n-k$ $0$'s. (You could instead use $0$ for yes, $1$ for no, doesn't matter as long as you are clear.) Now you need to specify the bijection in detail, that is, given a subset $S$ of $k$ elements, what is the associated sequence $f(S)$. And you need to say a little about how you know this $f$ is  a bijection,

Comment: Alright.  Thanks for the clarification.  You might want to put it as an answer so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of $k$-element subsets of our $n$-element set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.

Note that $A$ has $\dbinom{n}{k}$ elements. This might be useful later.

Let $B$ be the set of all $n$-bit strings that contain exactly $k$ $1$'s and therefore $n-k$ $0$'s.  Note that there are $\dbinom{n}{k}$ such strings, since the **location** of the $1$'s can be chosen  in $\dbinom{n}{k}$ ways.

There is a natural bijection $f$ from $B$ to $A$.  If we have an $n$-bit word $w=b_1b_2\dots b_n$, let $f(w)$ be the set of all $x_i$ such that the bit $b_i$ is equal to $1$.

We need to show that the function $f$ is a bijection from $B$ to $A$. Certainly $f(w)$ is a $k$-element subset of $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.  Now argue that $f$ is injective, and surjective. We really only need to deal with one of these, since we have already shown that $A$ and $B$ are of the same size.

**Remark:** We have used some fancy language, but there is nothing much going on.  We are at a cafeteria that has $n$ different foods, $x_1,\dots,x_n$. We have to place $k$ (different) foods on  our tray. The set of possible meal choices is just $A$.

We can write down in advance what our choices are going to be by writing an $n$-bit string, with a $1$ in the $i$-th place if we intend to put food $x_i$ on the tray, and a $0$ in the $i$-th place if we don't want food $x_i$ on the tray.

If we know the string, we know what we will be eating. If we know what we will be eating, we know the string.